Upper triangular block matrix
I want to do that :

It's a 3-3 matrix, with a star in the upper triangular region and a big zero in the lower. It doesn't seem possible to do that with nicematrix, because here the blocks are not rectangular.
I've tried to simply place these two symbols in the corner cases of an array, but it is not very convincing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
$\begin{pNiceArray}{ccc}
\lambda_1 & \Block{1-2}<\Huge>{\ \ast} & \\
 & \lambda_2 & \\
\mbox{\ \LARGE 0} & \ & \lambda_3
\end{pNiceArray}$
\end{document}

In particular my Eigenvalues are not well aligned anymore.


You can use a combination of\makebox(0,0) and \raisebox to display some content vertically shifted without altering the spacing of other cells. Something like:
\makebox(0,0){\raisebox{-6pt}{\text{\Large $\ast$}}}

\text{\Large $...$} changes the font size without changing the row height (as \Block{1-1}<\Large>{...} will do).
Example (adapt spacing as your want):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceArray}[cell-space-limits = 2pt]{ccc}
\lambda_1 & & \Block[l]{1-1}{\makebox(0,0)[t]{\raisebox{-6pt}{\text{\Large $\ast$}}}}\\
 & \lambda_2 & \\
\Block[r]{1-1}{\makebox(0,0)[b]{\raisebox{3pt}{\text{\Large $0$}}}} & & \lambda_3
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}



So good an idea, thank you so much!
